# Is a container service accessible via the cluster master?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

The Google Container Engine service doc https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/services/operations#sample_file states: 'To access the service, a client can connect to the cluster master endpoint...'

The service I deployed can be accessed on any of the cluster nodes via the service port, but not on the master.

kube-proxy instances which opened the service port are only running on the cluster nodes.

netstat does not show the service port as open on the cluster master.

Is the documentation correct?
If it is correct and I should be able to use the cluster master as endpoint, how would I go about debugging this issue?

Comment: Using this documentation instead helped clarify this for me: [Kubernetes Service Doc](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/services.md). Container Engine creates an externally visible 'load balancing' configuration delegating to the proxies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc is wrong, it should say `nodes` not `master`.

Comment: The documentation has been updated to say that you must connect to one of the nodes rather than the master.